# PostSharp Messages at ImportantInfo level not shown in Visual Studio error list

Tags: visual-studio, postsharp

I'm attempting to develop a simple aspect - `InformationAttribute` - based on `ScalarConstraint` whose purpose is to output/add to the Visual Studio error list at compile time a message. I'm wanting specifically an informational message rather than a warning, such that treating warnings as errors, etc., won't cause the compile to break; these messages are intended for, for example, reminding developers that using certain aspects in a project requires the use of a particular PostSharp plugin library, or that certain tests require particular external preconditions.

In theory, this should be simple, especially as I already have a working `WarningAttribute` that does the same job as a warning. However, simply changing the `SeverityType` in the call to `Message.Write`, thus:

```
public override void ValidateCode (object target)
{
    Message.Write (MessageLocation.Of (target),
                   SeverityType.ImportantInfo
                   "WA001",
                   this.reason) ;
}
```

Doesn't work, even though the [PostSharp documentation](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_extensibility_severitytype) states that messages written at `SeverityType.ImportantInfo` are shown in Visual Studio's Error List under Messages. I *can* confirm that, when `msbuild` is invoked from the command line, these messages are output to the console, but they don't show up in VS when the build is run from there.

I haven't found a good line of attack so far, or anyone having similar issues, unfortunately; has anyone resolved this or has a good approach to take to resolving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm this feature is broken and we don't know yet which part of the pipeline is to blame - PostSharp or Visual Studio.

You have two options: emit a warning, or [emit a tooltip](https://doc.postsharp.net/m_postsharp_extensibility_iweavingsymbolsservice_pushannotation_8513c902) using `IWeavingSymbolsService`. You can get this interface through `PostSharpEnvironment.CurrentProject.GetService.

I created a [bug report](https://support.postsharp.net/request/26668-messages-emitted-as-important-are-not) and we'll see if we can fix or if we will need to fix the documentation.